# Why is exec() not working with Tkinter END

Tags: python, file, tkinter, exec

FILE:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
    x = ""
    win = Tk()
    win.title("TEST")
    b = ""
    e = Text(width = 40)
    e.pack()
    def but ():
        global x
        global e
        global b
        global by
        e.config(state = "disabled")
        x = e.get("1.0", END)
        win.destroy()
    by = Button(width = 30, height = 10, text = "Publish", command = but)
    by.pack()
    win.mainloop()
    print("")
    print(x)
```

Code:

```
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
    def open_file():
        filepath = askopenfilename(
            filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")]
        )
        if not filepath:
            return
        with open(filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
            text = input_file.read()
            exec(text)
    open_file()
```

Error Code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 15, in but
NameError: name 'END' is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where is ```END``` defined?

Comment: It's defined in <from tkinter import *> i think

Comment: Just realized it's from the ```tkinter``` module.   Perhaps you should do a ```import tkinter``` and then refer to ```tkinter.END``` instead of just ```END```.  That's what I'd do; but there's probably a way to use ```END``` as is..   deferring to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename


def open_file():
    filepath = askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")]
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    with open(filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        return(text)


exec(open_file())
```

Answer was that you have to do exec(open_file()) out of the function and return(text)